# Selecting User details using Left Join Query

Tags: mysql

I have following 2 tables:

user_profile

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | first_name |  last_name  |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 17 | Hugh       | Jackman     |
| 18 | Keanu      | Reeves      |
| 19 | Tom        | Cruise      |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

like_posts

```
+---------+---------+
| post_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
| 31      | 18      |
| 31      | 19      |
+---------+---------+
```

I need the data: user_id, first_name, last_name from "user_profile" of all those users that has liked the post with post_id in "like_posts" table. For eg, if post_id is 31, then i want first_name and last_name of users where post_id = 31. Below is the desired result:

```
+------------+-------------+
| first_name |  last_name  |
+------------+-------------+
| Keanu      | Reeves      |
| Tom        | Cruise      |
+------------+-------------+
```

Here is my query that i have been trying and i am not getting desired result. I am getting details of all the users in the table. I am a beginner in mysql.

```
SELECT user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name FROM `user_profile` 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT like_posts.user_id from `like_posts` WHERE like_posts.post_id = 31
)
liked_users 
ON user_profile.id = liked_users.user_id
```

Comment: So whats wrong with your query?

Comment: I mentioned in post that I am getting details of all the users in the table. I should be getting desired results as i showed in table above again,

Comment: You specief in query 3 tables But you gave us only 2 table description.

Comment: 3rd table will be the result that i want, see in second table 2 users have liked the post with id "31" so i should get result of keanu and tom. hugh hasn't liked the deal "31". Thanks.

Comment: Thapaa , do you want Only matching records Or records that may or may not present in other table?

Comment: I want details of those user that has liked post_id. Whenever user like post then post_id and user_id is inserted into like_posts table . Thanks again.

Comment: @OP , Care to check answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b60ae/1

```
SELECT l.*, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM like_posts l
LEFT JOIN user_profile u
ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE l.post_id = 31
```

OR if you want just 2 columns:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM like_posts l
LEFT JOIN user_profile u
ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE l.post_id = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join to select matching records in both tables

```
SELECT user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name FROM `user_profile` 
JOIN `like_posts`

ON user_profile.user_id = like_posts.user_id      

 WHERE like_posts.post_id = 30
```